# Can the functions of a load balancer be performed with a mapreduce system?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am looking at using a MapReduce system to serve web pages and I have seen that load balancers are already used for distributing web page requests. Is there any reason that a map reduce system, Hadoop for example could not do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I know about Hadoop I doubt it could serve as a load balancer for webpage requests. Its intended purpose is distributed, batch processing of large datasets.